# Unable to communicate: Arduino with Bluetooth HC-06

Tags: arduino

I wrote a program that can capture moisture through a DHT11 sensor connected to an Arduino Uno. The captured value will be sent to an Android application using a Bluetooth HC-06 module. Everything works fine except that the latter (HC-06) does not send the captured moisture.

Can someone help me and thank you
The code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/* to communicate with the Bluetooth module's TXD pin */
#define BT_SERIAL_TX 10
/* to communicate with the Bluetooth module's RXD pin */
#define BT_SERIAL_RX 11
/* Initialise the software serial port */
SoftwareSerial BluetoothSerial(BT_SERIAL_RX, BT_SERIAL_TX);

// DHT-11 Configuration
#include <DHT.h> // lightweight DHT sensor library
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // DHT 11
#define TEMPTYPE 0 // Use 0 for Celsius, 1 for Fahrenheit
#define DHTPIN 2
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); // Define Temp Sensor

void setup() {
  BluetoothSerial.begin(115200); // Initialise BlueTooth
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //delay(1000);
  dht.begin(); // Initialize DHT Teperature Sensor
  BluetoothSerial.print("Starting ...");
}

void loop() {
  // Take readings
  float h = dht.readHumidity(); // Read humidity
  BluetoothSerial.println(h);
  delay(500);
}
```